# Java date to postgres Timestamp without timezone

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, date

In my postgres database one of the table has **Timestamp without timezone** value

> 2019-04-30 06:58:39.140661

I have the entity class where it is generated like this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="updated_ts")
private java.util.Date updatedTs;
```

I need to fetch values from db but I have date as **"MM/DD/YYY"**. So, what I need is to just check the month day and year and ignore the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use LocalDateTime instead of util.Date

Comment: You are mixing the wrong types. A `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in SQL and Postgres does *not* represent a moment. Without the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone, it has no precise meaning, The matching type in Java is `LocalDateTime`. In contrast, a `java.util.Date` does represent a moment. Furthermore, that terrible class was replaced years ago by `java.time.Instant`, both representing a moment in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/DD/YYYY")     
`@Column(name="updated_ts")
private java.util.Date updatedTs;`

or you can also use : **@Temporal(value=TemporalType.DATE)**